# Want scan last part id

Tags: jquery, regex

Want to get input with type=hidden and its id should have '1_id' at the end trying to find RegEx unable to do that. Kindly help in this Regard Asap. Thanks

```
JQUERY 
$('input[type=hidden]# $=*1_id')
Example HTML
<input id="sign_up_parameter_questions_attributes_1_id" type="hidden" value="15" name="sign_up_parameter[questions_attributes][1][id]">
```

Ideally above specified Jquery should able to find this tag

Comment: presto! - http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a regex:

```
$('input[id$="1_id"]')
```

and a [link to the jquery doc](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/)

Btw, if your `id` is **really unique** (as it should be), you can only use:

```
$('[id$="1_id"]')
```